# how to print polynomial equation using numpy?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I want print a polynomial equation for the given data. I am using this line of code, however I am not sure this the correct way to get the polynomial equation for the given data

```
fit2 = numpy.polyfit(temp[0][0],temp[0][1],deg=2)
y1=numpy.poly1d(fit2)
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

[Sympy](http://mattpap.github.io/scipy-2011-tutorial/html/index.html) has some nice features do that simply:

```
from sympy import Symbol,expand

fit2 = numpy.polyfit(temp[0][0],temp[0][1],deg=2)
y1=numpy.poly1d(fit2)

x=Symbol('x')
print(expand(y1(x)))
```

for:

```
-2.6666666666668*x**3 + 41.0000000000018*x**2 - 195.333333333342*x + 323.000000000013
```

Comment: does it works for 3 order regression coffeicent? Or how can I get regression regression formula applied for given data using numpy or any module